# When I move same commands into function program stops and while loop not working in STM32F0

Tags: stm32, c

I am developing library of LCD1602 for STM3232F030, I have header file like this:
LCD1602A.h

```
#include "delay.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f0xx.h"

#ifndef LCD1602A_H_
#define LCD1602A_H_
#define DATA_PORT GPIOA
#define CONTROL_PORT GPIOA
//Set pins
#define RS  6
#define RW  7
#define E   9
#define D4  10
#define D5  0
#define D6  1
#define D7  2
#define ON  3

int initLC1602A(void);
void send_4_bit_operation(void);
void send_8_bit_command(unsigned char command);
void send_8_bit_data(unsigned char d);
void write_string_LCD(char*);
void LCD_on(void);
void LCD_off(void);
void all_data_bits_zero(void);

#endif /* LCD1602A_H_ */
```

Using initialize function for prepare pins for use as LCD connections:

```
int initLC1602A(void){
    //Enable GPIOA Clock
    RCC->AHBENR|=RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
    //Set Pin Modes to Output

    GPIOA->MODER|=1<<2*E;
    GPIOA->MODER&=~(1<<(2*E+1));

    GPIOA->MODER|=1<<2*RS;
    GPIOA->MODER&=~(1<<(2*RS+1));
    GPIOA->MODER|=1<<2*RW;
    GPIOA->MODER&=~(1<<(2*RW+1));

    GPIOA->MODER|=1<<2*D4;
    GPIOA->MODER&=~(1<<(2*D4+1));
    GPIOA->MODER|=1<<2*D5;
    GPIOA->MODER&=~(1<<(2*D5+1));
    GPIOA->MODER|=1<<2*D6;
    GPIOA->MODER&=~(1<<(2*D6+1));
    GPIOA->MODER|=1<<2*D7;
    GPIOA->MODER&=~(1<<(2*D7+1));
    //Set pulldown

    GPIOA->PUPDR|=(1<<(2*E));
    GPIOA->PUPDR&=~1<<(1+2*E);

    GPIOA->PUPDR|=(1<<(2*ON));
    GPIOA->PUPDR&=~1<<(1+2*ON);

    GPIOA->PUPDR|=(1<<(2*RS));
    GPIOA->PUPDR&=~1<<(1+2*RS);
    GPIOA->PUPDR|=(1<<(2*RW));
    GPIOA->PUPDR&=~1<<(1+2*RW);

    GPIOA->PUPDR|=(1<<(2*D7));
    GPIOA->PUPDR&=~1<<(1+2*D7);
    GPIOA->PUPDR|=(1<<(2*D6));
    GPIOA->PUPDR&=~1<<(1+2*D6);
    GPIOA->PUPDR|=(1<<(2*D5));
    GPIOA->PUPDR&=~1<<(1+2*D5);
    GPIOA->PUPDR|=(1<<(2*D4));
    GPIOA->PUPDR&=~1<<(1+2*D4);

    //Set speed to high
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1<<(2*E));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=1<<(1+2*E);

    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1<<(2*ON));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=1<<(1+2*ON);

    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1<<(2*RS));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=1<<(1+2*RS);
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1<<(2*RW));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=1<<(1+2*RW);

    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1<<(2*D7));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=1<<(1+2*D7);
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1<<(2*D6));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=1<<(1+2*D6);
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1<<(2*D5));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=1<<(1+2*D5);
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1<<(2*D4));
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=1<<(1+2*D4);

    return 0;
}
```

For first action must send some commands like 4-Bit operation, I use this function:

```
void send_4_bit_operation(void){
    all_data_bits_zero();

    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<RS);
    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<RW);
    GPIOA->ODR|=1<<E;

    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<D7);
    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<D6);
    GPIOA->ODR|=1<<D5;
    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<D4);

    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<E);
}
void all_data_bits_zero(void)
{
    GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<(D7+16);
    GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<(D6+16);
    GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<(D5+16);
    GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<(D4+16);
}
```

But when I use **all_data_bits_zero()**, my main() function stops and never reach to while loop. But if I paste same commands inside function instead of that(shown in following), every thing works fine.

```
void send_4_bit_operation(void){
    GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<(D7+16);
    GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<(D6+16);
    GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<(D5+16);
    GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<(D4+16);

    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<RS);
    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<RW);
    GPIOA->ODR|=1<<E;
    
    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<D7);
    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<D6);
    GPIOA->ODR|=1<<D5;
    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<D4);
    
    GPIOA->ODR&=~(1<<E);
    }
```

This is my main():
int main(void)

```
{
    rpm=1000;
    //  Set SysTick for create 1 microsecond delay
    if(SysTick_Config(48000000/1000000))
    {
        while(1);
    }
    //FLASH
    FLASH->ACR|=FLASH_ACR_LATENCY;
    FLASH->ACR|=FLASH_ACR_PRFTBE;
    while(!(FLASH->ACR&FLASH_ACR_PRFTBS));
    //CLOCK
    RCC->CR|=RCC_CR_HSEON;
    while(!(RCC->CR&RCC_CR_HSERDY));
    RCC->CR&=~RCC_CR_PLLON;
    RCC->CFGR|=RCC_CFGR_PLLMUL6;
    RCC->CFGR|=RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC_HSE_PREDIV;
    RCC->CR|=RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while(!(RCC->CR|=RCC_CR_PLLRDY));
    RCC->CFGR|=RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    while(!(RCC->CFGR&RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL));
    RCC->CR|=RCC_CR2_HSI14ON;
    while(!(RCC->CR2|=RCC_CR2_HSI14RDY));

    RCC->APB2ENR|=RCC_APB2ENR_ADCEN;
    //  ADC1->CFGR2|=ADC_CFGR2_CKMODE_0;
    RCC->AHBENR|=RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
    //GPIO
    GPIOA->MODER|=GPIO_MODER_MODER4_0;
    GPIOA->PUPDR|=GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR4_0;
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR4;
    GPIOA->ODR|=GPIO_ODR_4;
    GPIOA->MODER|=GPIO_MODER_MODER5;
    //NVIC
    //  NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_COMP_IRQn);
    //  NVIC_SetPriority(ADC1_COMP_IRQn,0);
    //LCD1602A
    while(initLC1602A());
    //  Delay_us(100);
    send_4_bit_operation();
    //  simple_Delay(100);
    //Set 4-bit and 1-line
    //  send_8_bit_command(0x20);
    //Turn display on
    //  send_8_bit_command(0xE);
    //Set incremental
    //  send_8_bit_command(0x6);
    //  write_string_LCD("12");
    //  send_8_bit_data('1');

    //ADC
    ADC1->CR&=~ADC_CR_ADEN;
    ADC1->SMPR|=ADC_SMPR1_SMPR_2;
    ADC1->CFGR1|=ADC_CFGR1_CONT;
    ADC1->IER|=ADC_IER_EOSIE;
    ADC1->CHSELR|=ADC_CHSELR_CHSEL5;
    //  for(int i=0;i<10;i++);
    //  ADC1->CR|=ADC_CR_ADCAL;
    //  while(ADC1->CR&ADC_CR_ADCAL);
    //  calibration_factor=ADC1->DR;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++);
    ADC1->ISR|=ADC_ISR_ADRDY;
    ADC1->CR|=ADC_CR_ADEN;
    while(!(ADC1->ISR&=ADC_ISR_ADRDY));
    ADC1->CR|=ADC_CR_ADSTART;
    /* Loop forever */
    int counter=0;
    while(1){
        if(rpm<250){rpm=250;}
        int T=100000/rpm;
        int OnDelay=T/2;
        int OffDelay=T/2;
        GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<20;
        Delay_us(OffDelay);
        GPIOA->BSRR|=1<<4;
        Delay_us(OnDelay);
        counter++;
        if(counter==59)
        {
            GPIOA->ODR &=~GPIO_ODR_4;
            Delay_us(2*T);
            counter=0;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question? And what have you done to debug the situation?

Comment: @Justme: I want to know what is going on? and use that commands as function to to copy paste every where same codes, I debug mode, Everything goes fine.

Comment: Check that you've allocated enough stack space in your project. Every layer of function calls requires more space on the stack, so things failing when you put them into functions is a strong indicator that you have not allocated enough space to the stack.

Comment: @brhans: I doubled size of stack( to x800) in linker file. but it is same.

Comment: It could be anything really. What did your debugging reveal? Did you single step each instruction? You simply said you debugged it but saying you did is rather useless. Also, when that is fixed, you will have a non-working LCD library. The code violates the LCD bus timings in many places. And the sending of init commands to go into 4 bit mode may work only once on bootup. And the BSRR register can't be read, don't do a read-modify-write operation on it.

Comment: [Cross post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155011/when-i-move-same-commands-into-function-program-stops-and-while-loop-not-working)